# Add custom MIME to APACHE Tika?

Tags: java, mime, apache-tika

I am trying to add a custom mime type to Apache Tika.

I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info>
    <mime-type type="text/stringtemplategroup">
        <glob pattern="*.stg"/>
    </mime-type>
    <mime-type type="text/stringtemplate">
        <glob pattern="*.st"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

I am getting an error about a `Conflicting extension pattern .st`:

```
Caused by: org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypeException: Conflicting extension pattern: .st
    at org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypesReader.startElement(MimeTypesReader.java:166)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
```

How do I override the default entry for `*.st` extension and have it use my own?

Comment: Currently you don't, sorry. There's debate about making it possible but there's concern about how to properly warn users when they try to do something silly by mistake...